# Is there a better way to change pages once async data arrives?

Tags: swift, combine

I am new to Swift and am still getting a feel for things. In an app I am working on, I have a button that logs the user in. This is an API call, and the results of that data are then used to populate the next page. I do not want the page to change until the async data has arrived. My current approach to this is as follows:

1. User clicks the button which calls a function
2. The function uses sink/store to get the result, and then updates the `@ObservableObject`
3. The changes from the `@Published` field of loggedIn are received by and `Home` and the binding sets the NavigationLink as active.

This feels like a hack and given my inexperience with Swift, I'd say it is. How would this functionality be coded by someone more proficient in Swift?

```
class AsyncResponses : ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool = false
}
let asyncResponses = AsyncResponses()
```

```
struct Home: View {
    @ObservedObject var asyncResponseData = asyncResponses
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
                Button("Login") {
                     myApi.shared.login()
                }
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: UserIsLoggedInPage(),
                    isActive: $asyncResponseData.loggedIn
                ){EmptyView()}
         }
    }
}
```

```
class MyApi {
     static var shared = MyApi()
     private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
     private var api : SomeExternalCombineAPI
     init() {
         self.api = SomeExternalCombineAPI()
     }

     func login(){
        api.login()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in}) { result in
                // do stuff with result, etc. before finally ending with...
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    asyncResponses.loggedIn = true
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really cool thing you can do with values is to use the `didSet{}` functionality for a variable. For example.

```
var safeToNavigate: Bool = false
var someDataYoureWaitingFor: String? {
    didSet {
        safeToNavigate.toggle()
        //Or whatever other way you'd want to navigate to the next view. 
    }
}

func yourAsyncFunc() async -> String {
    //Your API Calls
    return someString
}

func yourCallerFunc() {
    someDataYoureWaitingFor = await yourAsyncFunc()
}
```

As with a setup like this, you could feasibly use the `safeToNavigate` to know when you can go to the next view or call whatever else you'd like to call from the `didSet`.

Comment: Arguably, I'm not "More Efficient" in swift lol. Thanks though haha